# Packing jQuery plugin - jFeed

Tags: jquery, packaging

I have a modified version of the jFeed plugin and now want to pack the four source files.

There is a Makefile and some perl scripts in the download but I don't know how to use them.

This is the file structure:

\Makefile
\proxy.php
\src\jatom.js
\src\jfeed.js
\src\jfeeditem.js
\src\jrss.js
\build\packer\jsPacker.pl
\build\packer\Pack.pm
\build\packer\ParseMaster.pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an online packer: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/